# matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor message of mismatch error: an L is missing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often use pcolor method of matplotlib but it sometimes gives me something like a dimension mismatch error that I don't understand. Here a sample code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

idx1 = 180
idx2 = 220
Range1 = range(idx1, idx2, 1)
Range2 = range(512)

z = np.random.randn( len( Range1 ), 512)

x, y = np.meshgrid( Range1 , Range2)
plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

As you can try by yourself the mismatch error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-7d51fd1b710e>", line 13, in <module>
    plt.pcolor(x, y, z)

  File "C:\Users\fedel\Anaconda2c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3083, in pcolor
    ret = ax.pcolor(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\fedel\Anaconda2c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1818, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\fedel\Anaconda2c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5168, in pcolor
    X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolor', *args, allmatch=False)

  File "C:\Users\fedel\Anaconda2c\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4996, in _pcolorargs
    C.shape, Nx, Ny, funcname))

TypeError: Dimensions of C (40L, 512L) are incompatible with X (40) and/or Y (512); see help(pcolor)
```

What is the difference between a "40L" dimension and a "40" without L dimension? And what do you suggest me to do in order to avoid this error and plot the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `L` is not the issue. That's an artifact of using an old Python version (Python 2 has two integer types).

It looks like your `z` (`C` to the `pcolor` method) has a transposed shape, 40 × 512 instead of 512 × 40:

```
for a in [x, y, z]:
    print(a.shape)
# (512, 40)
# (512, 40)
# (40, 512)
```

Transposing `z` makes it work: `plt.pcolor(x, y, z.T)`